# Redux saga why select do not block?

Tags: redux, redux-saga

Why saga use a non blocking operation to retrive a value from an in memory object? Wouldn't be better just use a blocking operation like getState?

Answer (score 0):

In redux-saga `yield select()` is synchronize, I don't understand why you say it's non blocking, or you should post more detail?
Use select effect but not call `getState` directly is good for test.

Comment: The docs definitely say it is NON-blocking. https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#blocking--non-blocking

Comment: to Slbox: Thanks for you mention, I say `select` is a synchronize effect, means it will complete immediately, `Blocking` or `Non blocking` doesn't matter. Maybe the docs means `Non blocking` is synchronize.